# App Engine + DNS: myapp.com/* is working but not www.myapp.com/*

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I'm trying to set up a custom domain for my App Engine project. My A records are:

```
@   216.239.32.21   1 Hour  
@   216.239.34.21   1 Hour  
@   216.239.36.21   1 Hour  
@   216.239.38.21   1 Hour  
www 216.239.32.21   1 Hour  
www 216.239.34.21   1 Hour  
www 216.239.36.21   1 Hour  
www 216.239.38.21   1 Hour
@   2001:4860:4802:32::15   1 Hour  
@   2001:4860:4802:34::15   1 Hour  
@   2001:4860:4802:36::15   1 Hour  
@   2001:4860:4802:38::15   1 Hour  
www 2001:4860:4802:32::15   1 Hour  
www 2001:4860:4802:34::15   1 Hour  
www 2001:4860:4802:36::15   1 Hour  
www 2001:4860:4802:38::15   1 Hour
```

and my domain redirect shows: Redirect the naked domain `http://myapp.com to http://app-id=<app_id>,domain=myapp.myapp.com`

I see the following:

1. When I go to myapp.com/link/to/url, it loads the resource
2. When I go to www.myapp.com/link/to/url, I get a 404: `The requested URL /link/to/url was not found on this server. That’s all we know.`
3. When I go to myapp.com, it redirects to www.myapp.com, which again gives the above error.
4. I can't change the "naked domain redirect", I get some kind of a server error, not much more information.

What can I do so that any/all resources show up, whether its myapp.com or www.myapp.com or myapp.com/* or www.myapp.com/*

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding `www` as a cname record and not as an A record. Point it to `ghs.googlehosted.com`. You have to add each version of a domain/subdomain separately. Here are the [app-engine docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain) about that

Also, you use a [dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/routing) to direct different urls to different modules.